# Anychart datetime on the y_axis

Tags: oracle, datetime, oracle-apex, linechart, anychart

I am trying to show a trend of processes that run every day over time. Therefore I have a date which I call processing date, which I want to be shown on the X-Axis, and an end_time (date timestamp) since the end time can finish before or after midnight. Therefore I would like to be able to plot the data on the Y axis. I am using Oracle APEX v5, not sure which version of Anychart is running behind, maybe this is version related?

So far, I have not figured out a way for the values returned by my query to be plotted correctly when the values are dates. Is this possible? These are the settings of the y_axis, which when used do not show any data on the graph.

```
                <y_axis >
                    <scale type="DateTime" mode="Normal"    />
                    <title enabled="false" />
                    <labels enabled="true" position="Outside">
                        <font family="Tahoma" size="10" color="0x000000" />
                        <format>
                            <![CDATA[{%Value}]]>
                        </format>
                    </labels>
                    <major_grid enabled="False"/>
                    <minor_grid enabled="False"/>
                </y_axis>
```

When I convert the dates to a number, they are plotted correctly, but so far I had no luck with trying to convert them back to a date using the settings/locale:

```
<settings> 
 <locale>
  <date_time_format>
    <format>%yyyy%MM%dd%HH%mm%ss</format>
  </date_time_format>
 </locale>
    <animation enabled="false"/>
    <no_data show_waiting_animation="False">
        <label>
            <text>#NO_DATA_MESSAGE#</text>
            <font family="Verdana" bold="yes" size="10"/>
        </label>
    </no_data>
</settings>
```

I am using this to generate the test points with values:

select null as link, trunc (sysdate) as label, to_char((sysdate),'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') as end_time from dual
union
select null as link, trunc (sysdate)-1 as label, to_char((sysdate)-1,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') as end_time from dual
order by label;

The Value of the point ends up being "2016%MM20%HH00%ss", I tried changing the upper/lower case of the formatting to no avail. From the output it looks like the %vars cannot be used concatenated, but if that is the case, then I cannot use values to convert the dates...

Maybe this is conceptually wrong, but so far I have not found a way to plot these correctly. I hope someone can shed some light on this.

Thank you in advance.

Edit:

I managed to do it ignoring the XML from Apex and creating my own datapoints (I will post the complete answer later), this is a sample of the XML:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone = "yes"?>
<anychart>
    <settings>
        <animation enabled="false" />
        <no_data show_waiting_animation="False">
            <label>
                <text>No data found</text>
                <font family="Verdana" bold="yes" size="10" />
            </label>
        </no_data>
        <locale>
            <date_time_format>
                <format>
                    <![CDATA[%dd-%MM-%yyyy %HH:%mm]]>
                </format>
            </date_time_format>
        </locale>
    </settings>
    <margin left="0" top="0" right="0" bottom="0" />
    <charts>
        <chart plot_type="CategorizedVertical" name="chart_52322125829114359521">
            <chart_settings>
                <title enabled="False" />
                <chart_background>
                    <fill type="Solid" color="0xffffff" opacity="0" />
                    <border enabled="false" />
                    <corners type="Square" />
                </chart_background>
                <data_plot_background></data_plot_background>
                <axes>
                    <y_axis>
                        <scale type="DateTime" mode="Normal" />
                        <title enabled="false" />
                        <labels enabled="true" position="Outside">
                            <font family="Tahoma" size="10" color="0x000000" />
                            <format>
                                <![CDATA[{%Value}{dateTimeFormat:%HH:%mm}]]>
                            </format>
                        </labels>
                        <major_grid enabled="True" interlaced="false">
                            <line color="Black" />
                        </major_grid>
                        <minor_grid enabled="True"></minor_grid>
                    </y_axis>
                    <x_axis>
                        <scale type="DateTime" mode="Normal" />
                        <title enabled="false" />
                        <labels enabled="true" position="Outside">
                            <font family="Tahoma" size="10" color="0x000000" />
                            <format>
                                <![CDATA[{%Value}{dateTimeFormat:%ddd %dd-%MM-%yyyy}]]>
                            </format>
                        </labels>
                        <major_grid enabled="True" interlaced="false">
                            <line color="Black" />
                        </major_grid>
                        <minor_grid enabled="True"></minor_grid>
                    </x_axis>
                </axes>
                <legend enabled="true" position="Right" align="Near" elements_layout="Vertical">
                    <title enabled="False"/>
                    <icon>
                        <marker enabled="true" />
                    </icon>
                    <font family="Tahoma" size="10" color="0x000000" />
                </legend>
            </chart_settings>
            <data_plot_settings enable_3d_mode="false" default_series_type="Line">
                <line_series>
                    <tooltip_settings enabled="true">
                        <format>
                            <![CDATA[{%SeriesName} {%Name} {%Value}{dateTimeFormat:%HH:%mm}]]>
                        </format>
                        <font family="Tahoma" size="10" color="0x000000" />
                        <position anchor="Center" valign="Top" halign="Center" padding="10" />
                    </tooltip_settings>
                    <label_settings enabled='&LABEL.' mode="Outside" multi_line_align="Center">
                        <format>
                            <![CDATA[{%Value}{dateTimeFormat:%HH:%mm}]]>
                        </format>
                        <background enabled="false" />
                        <font family="Tahoma" size="10" color="0x000000" />
                    </label_settings>
                    <line_style>
                        <line enabled="true" thickness="2" opacity="1" />
                    </line_style>
                    <marker_settings enabled="True" >
                        <marker type="HLine" />
                    </marker_settings>
                </line_series>
            </data_plot_settings>
            <data>
                <series name="AEG" type="Line">
                    <point name="01-03-2016 00:00" y="01-01-2001 23:35"></point>
                    <point name="02-03-2016 00:00" y="01-01-2001 23:16"></point>
                    <point name="03-03-2016 00:00" y="01-01-2001 23:20"></point>
                    <point name="04-03-2016 00:00" y="01-01-2001 23:32"></point>
                    <point name="07-03-2016 00:00" y="01-01-2001 23:28"></point>
                    <point name="08-03-2016 00:00" y="01-01-2001 23:24"></point>
                    <point name="09-03-2016 00:00" y="01-01-2001 23:14"></point>
                    <point name="10-03-2016 00:00" y="01-01-2001 23:30"></point>
                    <point name="11-03-2016 00:00" y="01-01-2001 23:54"></point>
                    <point name="14-03-2016 00:00" y="01-01-2001 23:52"></point>
                    <point name="15-03-2016 00:00" y="01-01-2001 23:27"></point>
                    <point name="16-03-2016 00:00" y="01-01-2001 23:51"></point>
                    <point name="17-03-2016 00:00" y="01-01-2001 23:34"></point>
                    <point name="18-03-2016 00:00" y="01-01-2001 23:32"></point>
                    <point name="21-03-2016 00:00" y="02-01-2001 00:02"></point>
                </series>
            </data>
        </chart>
    </charts>
</anychart>
```

A new question is, can you help me understand why the tooltip does not get the correct value on the %Name?

```
                        <![CDATA[{%SeriesName} {%Name} {%Value}{dateTimeFormat:%HH:%mm}]]>
```

In the tooltip I am getting the following text on the first point is **AEG 01-01-1970 00:00 23:35** and I was expecting, based on the name **01-03-2016 00:00 23:35**

Thanks!

Comment: It seems to be something with the query, but it is hard to understand without seeing the resulting XML output APEX produces. If you provide this XML output we can probably determine where the problem is.

Comment: I just edited the original post with an XML that works for me, but I have one question that maybe you can answer on it? Thanks!